# Gitlab-CI.yml não compartilha stages

Tags: angular, docker, gitlab, integração-contínua

Estou tentando automatizar um build utilizando o gitlab-ci.yml, porém estou tendo alguns problemas. Aparentemente cada stage cria um novo container da imagem que eu escolhi. Adianto que sou novo nesse mundo de CI/CD então talvez a maneira que eu esteja fazendo as coisas não seja a mais apropriada. Segue o script e o retorno obtido:

> .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - deploy

Preparando ambiente:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq
    - apt-get install -qq npm curl wget
    - npm i -g n
    - n latest
    - apt-get autoclean -qq
  only:
    refs: 
      - dev
    changes:
      - "**/*.ts"
      - "**/*.html"
      - "**/*.css"
      - "**/*.js"

Build Angular:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd view &&  npm run build
    - echo "Build - OK"
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
    changes:
      - "**/*.ts"
      - "**/*.html"
      - "**/*.css"
      - "**/*.js"

Deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:  
    - ls -la view/dist
  only:
    refs:
      - dev


cache:
  paths:
    - view/dist
    - view/node_modules
```

Ao comitar na dev quando passa do primeiro stage para o segundo ele não consegue fazer uso da dependência instalada anteriormente. Eu sei que posso colocar tudo no before_script porém ele vai ficar atualizando a distro e refazendo a instalação para todos os passos, mas fica muito lento.

Alguém poderia me ajudar em como proceder? Obrigado.

> Retorno

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.2.0 (a987417a)
  on 781023241e32 EkxrYDXp
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:18.04 ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:18.04 ...
Using docker image sha256:a2a15febcdf362f6115e801d37b5e60d6faaeedcb9896155e5fe9d754025be12 for ubuntu:18.04 ...
Running on runner-EkxrYDXp-project-44-concurrent-0 via 781023241e32...
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/teste/angular-teste/.git/
Checking out 37ff685b as dev...
Removing view/node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/index-v5/0b/
Removing view/node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/index-v5/21/
Removing view/node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/index-v5/57/
Removing view/node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/index-v5/88/b7/
Removing view/node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/index-v5/a3/
Removing view/node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/index-v5/ef/
Removing view/node_modules/.cache/terser-webpack-plugin/tmp/

Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
$ cd view &&  npm run build
/bin/bash: line 78: npm: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Definir o `cache` globalmente é a abordagem que permite que você compartilhe as dependências geradas entre os jobs. Aqui tem um [exemplo de dependências do NodeJS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/caching/#caching-nodejs-dependencies).

Você já está fazendo isso, porém **está especificando os paths sem a `/` no fim**, então o Gitlab está tentando fazer cache de arquivos em vez de uma estrutura de diretórios. Tente definir seu cache global da seguinte forma:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - view/dist/
    - view/node_modules/
```

Comment: Legal Eduardo, mas olhando o meu erro. Como eu poderia fazer a instalação dos pacotes do SO ficarem no cache? (Stage: prepare do meu yml).